# Windows Server 2012 Telnet connection lost port 25

Tags: windows-server-2012, smtp, telnet

I am new to Windows servers, I have Windows Server 2012 and I am trying to set up and enable mail server (SMTP). I have followed [this](http://blog.hyperfive.com/2013/07/how-to-setup-internal-smtp-service-for.html) tutorial to instal and enable SMTP server and completed it successfully. Now I would like to test my server, I installed Telnet and ran this command:

```
open localhost 25
```

I get a line that says:

```
press any key to continue....
```

and if I do anything I get a message:

```
connection to host lost.
```

Question: What could be the most likely cause of this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect access restriction to the service.

Its the step 6 of your tutorial.

If its setup correctly be sure you have no antivirus that scan/restrict the port 25. It can cause such issue too.

Comment: I fixed the issue by setting up port forwarding on my router and using my domain name instead of a localhost.